# Gradle build gets stuck on mergeDebugResources on centos

Tags: android, gradle, build, centos

I'm compiling an android project on a centos server using gradle and after using `gradle build` everything works fine until this:

> > Building 17% > :app:mergeDebugResources

and then it just gets stuck there.

Comment: Have you had any progress on this? I'm experiencing it now but it didn't happen on the same project a few weeks ago, and also happens only on one development machine

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe I can't name it a progress but I had to update all the resources related to project. but it was just the beginning... after that I got received errors that was about linux access file and it wasn't sth that you could handle by `chown` or `chmod` the final solution was changing the linux server into windows server and finally it worked.

Comment: I have this problem in windows server. any fixes?

Comment: I have this too... any fixes?

Comment: @SaeedVaziry the solution to me was moving the project into windows severer, but as I can see you're having this problem there too